# Is it possible for a calculator to be completely exact?

Tags: computer-science, calculator

Once you have reached perhaps 10 decimal places, calculators can make rounding errors and so on. Is it possible to build a calculator that makes none of these errors? For example, it could work out each decimal place of an irrational number – as you click a button it gives, say, 10 more digits. (Obviously, it wouldn't be able to give you "all" the digits, but could it keep on computing more indefinitely.)

Comment: That's really interesting. I really have no idea how they could have done that (I've heard using binary at the most fundamental level can create all kinds of rounding errors when using an online calculator – obviously this does not affect everyday calculations though).

Comment: Most modern calculators can do this upto very high precisions, but there will be a limit somwhere.

Comment: Also, I assume you only mean computable numbers (not every number is computable)

Comment: @Peter Does computable mean a recurring decimal? Because often on scientific calculators I have seen $1/3$ represented as $0.\bar3$

Comment: No, "computable" means that there is an algorithm that can, in principle, calculate all the digits. Many programs use fractions, which avoids already many rounding errors. Of course, no real computer can store an irrational number exactly.

Comment: Interesting... Joe you might want to look up halting problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: For daily life purposes, software tools like pari/gp are unimaginably more accurate than it would be needed. You can calcuate most (also irrational) numbers easily upto millions or at least thousands of digits. But I am not sure you ask about this.

Comment: @ganeshie8 I do not think the question is about decidable problems, it seems to be about the computabilty and the accuracy.

Comment: How would such a calculator compute and display $2 \pi$ "exactly"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Not "exactly" in that sense. However, it could give you 10 digits (with no rounding errors) and you could click a button and then it would give you another 10 and so on.

Comment: @Joe:  That's not your question, "Is it possible to build a calculator that makes none of these errors?"  The answer to your question is "no."  If you want to change your question, do so... but I assure you that it annoys anyone who would otherwise want to help you.  Also, not even all the computer memory on the web is sufficient to represent a transcendental number such as $\pi$ (of course), so any limited computer is hopelessly inadequate for the task you asked about.

Comment: @David G. Stork I did say in my original question that it would only give you about 10 digits, and then it can keep on computing them in chunks. If this was possible, then you would never need to display all the digits.

Comment: My point is that, at least in theory, there is no limit to how many times you can click a button and it gives you more digits should you desire it. There are also no errors in the digits displayed.

Comment: @David  https://pi2e.ch/blog/2016/10/31/hexadecimal-digits-of-pi/  depends on how you display them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with calculations made in software:
1-Programming inaccuracy (e.g. choice of rounding/truncation point, wrong use of floating point arithmetic, etc.)
2-Limited Precision in a given language/machine
3-Compounded errors resulting from a sequence of applied operations on a number where each operation adds to the error.
4-Working with subtraction, division between numbers with very small difference.

Most importantly translating real numbers to computer representation. For example $\frac{1}{3}=0.333333...$ dos not end in mathematics, however computer memory is finite.

Here comes your question, and I think that your idea is possible to some extent. Any result you see in a calculator depends on software and hardware. The software could be programmed to control:

1-Truncation rules.

2-Rounding rules.

3-Use special formulas that could reduce calculation errors rather than apply the algebraic formula directly.

4-Enhancing the precision in calculation using special libraries for example, a 128-bit quadruple precision is designed not only for applications requiring results in higher than double precision: [Wiki-Quad Precision Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)

However, you can't easily control the accumulated error in calculations without having explicit algorithms that relate the desired precision to the precision required on operands and intermediate results.

As for hardware, I am sure that CPU and memory abilities are improving rapidly. Calculators using today's OS environment could take advantage of modern CPU architecture (e.g. Calculators on mobile devices). However, calculators build on special processors and used by regular people may not always offer the flexibility or power of the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

As long as we're only talking about rational numbers, one can easily program a computer to represent them all exactly -- just store them as a pair of arbitrary-precision numerator and denominators.

This is much slower (and uses much more memory) than the usual approximate "floating-point" representation, and since floating point is usually more than precise enough for our purposes, exact rational arithmetic is only used in those special cases where there is a concrete need for it.

On the other hand, this won't help us represent *irrational* numbers like logarithms, square roots, sines, $\pi$, and so forth.

You can pick a particular *subset* of the irrationals -- for example "all numbers you can compute by starting from integers and repeatedly taking roots and/or ordinary arithmetic operations", and compute *symbolically* with those. Then the computer might represent the result of some operations as (and display it as) "$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt3 + \sqrt{17}}}{2+\sqrt5}$". But this becomes even slower, and in many cases not as *useful* as a decimal approximation anyway.

And as you want to support more and more operations, the *algorithms* you need to operate symbolically on the results quickly become extremely complex. Practically the risk of bugs in those algorithms rise even faster. And the algorithms have to be *invented* in the first place -- we'd want a reliable way to test if two symbolic expressions are the same number, for example, but it's not obvious how to do that. We don't even *know*, for example, if there's any integer polynomial relation between $e$ and $\pi$, so how would we begin to compare a polynomial in $e$ and $\pi$ to "$0$"?

At some point we might decide to cut our losses and instead say we are operating on *computable numbers* and represent each number by a *program* that knows how to approximate that number by arbitrary-precision rationals. Then at least it seems to be fairly trivial to do *arithmetic* on such programs. Unfortunately, this would mean that it is now *provably* undecidable whether such a number is smaller or greater than a given rational, due to the halting problem. So we wouldn't even be able to compute the first $n$ decimal digits of the number reliably -- not much of an "exact" representation for practical purposes.

(The details of this are sensitive to exactly how we define "program that approximates the number in question". Working with "programs that produce a rational sequence that converge to our number" is different from "programs that compares our number to a rational given as input" and problems turn up at different stages in the development of them. But problems always do turn up).